# Need to convert raw sql to eloquent query builder

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I need to convert the following sql query to eloquent query builder.

```
select * from projects
inner join assigned_projects on projects.id = assigned_projects.project_id
where assigned_projects.user_id=9;
```

where projects and assigned_projects are in many to many relation. Please help me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
$project = DB::table('projects')
             ->join('assigned_projects' , 'projects.id' , '=', 'assigned_projects.project_id')
             ->where('assigned_projects.user_id', '=', 9)
             ->get();
```

Comment: I came across with this one :   DB::table('projects')
                ->join('assigned_projects', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('projects.id', '=', 'assigned_projects.project_id')
                        ->where('assigned_projects.user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id);
                })
                ->get(); But your solutions also do the job done right. Thanks !

Comment: Another question, I need to access client name from $project like $project->client->username . But that solution is not working in that case. How will I do that ?